# which MVVM framework is good for SL4?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

1. MVVM foundation (by Josh Smith)
2. MVVM light tollkit.

   I am using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express

Answer (score 1):

So what's the question?  I like MVVM Light, but that's already listed in your question.  Are you looking for advice on how to use it?

I haven't use Josh Smith's, but MVVM Light has a really nice Messenger class for communicating between ViewModels, a generic RelayCommand implementation, and some other sugar here and there.

Answer (score 1):

MVVM Light is indeed  very nice one.  I edit the templates though to get rid of all the comments.

I Always add a custom base class to add some utility methods (eg. a generic RaisePropertyChangedhandler)

Answer (score 1):

Another few to consider are:

1. [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) : An opinionated developer focused MVVM Framework
2. [Reactive UI](https://github.com/xpaulbettsx/reactiveui) : Based on the Reactive Extensions Framework

Both of these are great MVVM frameworks and use very different methods to implement MVVM, The fun bit is trying them out. :)

Answer (score 0):

MVVM is a design pattern ... so really, no libraries are required. The question is, what Library offers the best suport for the type/size of application that you're creating... MVVM Light is a great library to start with - easy and a nice small footprint.